# Is there anyway to view my TTT stats?

Tags: garrys-mod, trouble-in-terrorist-town

I really want to know my TTT stats, how can I view them?

Answer (score 1):

What do you specifically mean by TTT stats? Every server you go on with TTT stores your "stats" separately. I'm assuming you mean your **karma/kills/deaths etc**, you can view them by pressing and holding **TAB** while in a TTT server. Some TTT servers have a custom shop where you can buy **hats/clothes** with currency you earned while playing, this can be accessed using **F4**.

Hope this helped, good luck!